# How to parse data from two json by using AssyncTask method?

Tags: android, json

I have seen one similar question to this, but i couldn't solve my problem like he did. 
Here i'm getting data from url:

```
public class AsyncHttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        Integer result = 0;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            // 200 represents HTTP Ok
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);
                }
                parseResult(response.toString());
                result = 1; // Successful
            } else {
                result = 0; //"Failed to fetch data!";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return result; //"Failed to fetch data!";
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        // Download complete. Let us update UI
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (result == 1) {
            giftListAdapter = new GiftListAdapter(GiftsActivity.this, gifts);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(giftListAdapter);
        } else {
            SuperActivityToast.create(GiftsActivity.this, getString(R.string.no_internet_connection),
                    SuperToast.Duration.SHORT, Style.getStyle(Style.RED, SuperToast.Animations.FLYIN)).show();
        }
    }
}

private void parseResult(String result) {
    try {
        JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("gifts");
        gifts = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject post = posts.optJSONObject(i);
            GiftItem item = new GiftItem();
            item.setThumbnail(post.optString("image"));
            item.setTitle(post.optString("title"));
            item.setDescription(post.optString("description"));
            item.setSource(getString(R.string.source) + " " + post.optString("source"));
            item.setTotalRating(post.optInt("rating"));
            item.setPrice(post.optDouble("price"));

            gifts.add(item);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here i'm executing that url. I'm trying now to parse this second url and load all items after first data is loaded:

```
new AsyncHttpTask().execute(url_movies);
        new AsyncHttpTask().execute(url_books); // This is the second url i'm trying to get
```

How could i do that?

Comment: is both url returning same type json

Comment: Yes, both are returning same type json

Comment: If i put both urls in execute method i will get the second url, but first not.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying now to parse this second url and load all items after first
>   data is loaded:

Then instead of calling `execute` method just after first, call it inside  `onPostExecute` method when first url all items are loaded successfully.

Also add  second call in `if-else` block to avoid it execute again :

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        // Download complete. Let us update UI
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ... your code here
        if(params[0].equals(url_movies)){
           new AsyncHttpTask().execute(url_books);
        } 
    }
```

also add

Comment: I can't access String params.

Comment: @DusanDimitrijevic: ok create a String variable in `AsyncHttpTask` class like `String strUrl;`, assign value to it in `doInBackground` method `strUrl=params[0]` and use `strUrl` in if condition `if(strUrl.equals(url_movies))` in `onPostExecute `

Comment: I have get only data from url_books and not from url_movies .

Comment: and if i would want to parse maybe from one more json, how would i do that also? Thank you.

Comment: @DusanDimitrijevic: create methods for both json parsing and called it inside `doInBackground ` according to url from which getting json data

Answer (score 0):

If you want both urls than send them as an String array like this

String urls[] = new String[]{"url1" , "url2"};

new AsyncHttpTask().execute(urls);

and in doinbackground method exec them like 
url1 = params[0];
url2 = params[1];

Comment: Okay, but how to change in doinbackground method params?

Comment: Navin, i'm not sure what should i change in doInBackground method? Could you help me with that?

Comment: params arguments of doinbackground method are those parameters which you passed in execute method